# webstorm autocomplete for require(.json)

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Webstorm is pretty smart when providing auto completion for node.js modules.
unfortunatelly for some reason if the required module is a json file i.e

```
var settings = require('./settings.json);
```

it does require it and build an object with the data but, no autocomplete is provided in the editor.

Anyone have any solutions for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug, logged as [WEB-10568](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10568).

The issue has been marked as **Fixed** since this answer was originally posted.